# Is there gas exchange in the fingers?

Tags: human-physiology

I saw A documentary many years ago that said that hemoglobin will take in O2 in the fingers and toes. I have Not been able to find any information on this. But it would seem that being so close to the surface some gas exchange would occur, and more so in the fingers and toes than the teunk.

Answer (score 2):

At first I was skeptical about this question but then I did some researching and apparently, a certain amount of oxygen is indeed taken up from the surroundings through the upper layers of our skin. In fact, the paper titled "[The cutaneous uptake of atmospheric oxygen contributes significantly to the oxygen supply of human dermis and epidermis.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11826181) states that

> the upper skin layers to a depth of of 0.25-0.40 mm are almost
>   exclusively supplied by external oxygen, whereas the oxygen transport
>   of the blood has a minor influence.

[Here is another paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18423195) that you would find interesting. In short, I would say that its not just the fingers but O2 diffusion into cells take place over the whole body.